# How to read key value pair in cocos2dx from txt file?

Tags: cocos2d-x

I this is the first time I am developing for BB10 OS using cocos2dx.

I need to read key value pair in Cocos2Dx.

eg: Skill= 5
    Power= Awesome

The target  is Blackberry 10OS and using QNX Momentics for development.
Is there a library for this?
Or as an alternate approach, if this can be a stored in a lua file, then how to parse the lua file to retrive these values, based on keys?

Answer (score 0):

cocos2d-x can parse .plist and store it in a CCDictionary. I suggest you use a plist rather than a normal txt file.

If you are using XCode, you can create from there.

To load the plist and store it in the dictionary, you can do this:

```
const char *plistPath = CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->fullPathFromRelativePath("myplist.plist");
CCDictionary *myKeyValuePairDictionary = CCDictionary::createWithContentsOfFileThreadSafe(pszPath);
```